# Python merging variables

Tags: python, variables

I have a question about merging multiple variables containing text. Each subject in the data set has 10 variables `(description1, description2,.....,description10)`. All of these variables contain 2-3 lines of text for each subject.  However, I need to combine all of the descriptions(1-10) to create a variable called `all_descriptions` for each subject that contains all ten of there descriptions in 1 variable. I’m stuck on how to do this, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: `' '.join(descriptions)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate them:

```
desc_list = (description1, description2,.....,description10)
all_descriptions = ''
for i in desc_list:
    all_descriptions += i
```

or as a one-liner:

```
all_descriptions = ''.join(desc_list)
```